# PHP Property of non object - Variable inside of URL

Tags: php

I am getting an error when trying to apply a dynamic variable into the URL, which it self also is set into a variable, `$sURL`.

If I change `.$prNameUrl.` to the keyword CATS for example it works fine. But as soon as I enter a variable I get the error:

> **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**

```
$prNameUrl = $v->product_name.' '.$v->product_category.' '.$v->product_format;


$prNameUrlTwo = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?q='.$prNameUrl.'&count=4&mkt=en-US';

$sURL = $prNameUrlTwo;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxxxxxxx'
));
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$myContents = json_decode($contents);
if(count($myContents->value) > 0) {
    foreach ($myContents->value as $imageContent) {

        echo "<a href='{$imageContent->webSearchUrl}'><img src='{$imageContent->thumbnailUrl}' width='290' height='200' /></a>";

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$prNameUrl`? What is the content of `$contents`? (probably false).

Comment: $prNameUrl is in this case "Trackmania Turbo Games Playstation 4"

Comment: @Swift123 What is the content o `$v` variable? Probably it's not an object

Comment: $contents is retrieving a wide range of data from Bings Image Search Api, which is set into an stdClass Object. I am getting "WebsearchUrl", "Name", "thumbnailURL", "width", "height", "content size" etc... The only things I am interested in is "websearchurl" and "thumbnail url".

Comment: claudio: $v->product_name is "Trackmania Turbo, $v->product_category is "Games" and $v->product_format is "Playstation 4".

Comment: @Swift123 is it though? Have you dumped the content out and checked (both variables)

Comment: @JonStirling, what are you referring to exactly?

Comment: `var_dump($myContents, $contents, $prNameUrl);` What's the output?

Comment: @Swift123 what's the output of `var_dump($v);`?

Comment: if i do not add a variable to the URL and change it to....images/search?q=TRACKMANIA&count...... then I don't get this error. Then I get the images that i want. But when I add the variable into the URL, like this .....images/search?q='.$prNameUrl.'&count.... then the problem occurs.

Comment: @JonStirling, I cannot get the output since I only get the non object error at the moment.

Comment: @claudio NULL object(stdClass)#5 (7) { ["product_name"]=> string(16) "Trackmania Turbo" ["product_format"]=> string(13) "Playstation 4" ["product_category"]=> string(5) "Games" ["product_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" ["product_id"]=> string(4) "4145" ["product_price_lowest"]=> string(1) "0" ["product_price_highest"]=> string(3) "300" }

Comment: @Swift123 NULL is the output of what? Which line is the error?

Comment: @claudio if(count($myContents->value) > 0)

Comment: @Swift123 please post the output of `var_dump($myContents);`

Comment: @claudio it is NULL

Comment: As I have stated before. For some reason, it does not allow entering a variable to be entered into the URL that later on goes into the "curl_setopt".

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with "urlencode".

```
$sURL = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $prNameUrl . '\'') . '&count=4&mkt=en-US';
```

**FULL CODE WITH SOLUTION**

```
$prNameUrl = $v->product_name.' '.$v->product_category.' '.$v->product_format;
echo $prNameUrl;
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';

$prNameUrlTwo = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search?q=';

$WebSearchURL = $prNameUrlTwo ;

$sURL = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $prNameUrl . '\'') . '&count=4&mkt=en-US';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxxxxxxxx'
));
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$myContents = json_decode($contents);
if(count($myContents->value) > 0) {
    foreach ($myContents->value as $imageContent) {

        echo "<a href='{$imageContent->webSearchUrl}'><img src='{$imageContent->thumbnailUrl}' width='290' height='200' /></a>";

    }
}
```